Invoking W3Schools CodeColor library on multiple elements
I want to offer code examples and I am using a JS code highlighter with an ID. See this URL for the working demo: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_syntax_highlight
I want to use this for multiple examples but the ID only works once. I have tried both ID and Class but this still doesn't work.
w3CodeColor(document.getElementById("myDiv")); // only works for 1 element
w3CodeColor(document.getElementByClassName("myDiv")); // does not work

The example code what I have tried is below,
<div class="myDiv">code example goes here</div>

<div id="myDiv">code example goes here</div>

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Please don't re-post, edit then wait for it to be reviewed.

I'd suggest you delete that other question now you've provided detail here.

W3Schools is widely known to have incomplete, outdated, or flat out incorrect information. You would be wise to stay as far away from it as possible and instead use a recognized authority like the Mozilla Developer Network.

The W3Schools library is badly designed in so much as it expects only a single element to be provided to it. getElementsByClassName() returns a collection, so is not compatible.
To fix this you will need to loop through every .myDiv element and call w3CodeColor() on them individually.
document.querySelectorAll(".myDiv").forEach(div => w3CodeColor(div));

However, a much better approach would be to use a different, better written library which does syntax highlighting much more effectively - for example https://highlightjs.org/

hey Rory, you mean like this w3CodeColor(document.getElementByClassName("myDiv").forEach(div => w3CodeColor(div)); this doesn't work

You're right - apologies. Updated the answer to fix the problem. Here's a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1uy5fw2L/
